# Angular 2 : Cannot find module './data.service angular 2

Tags: angular, rest, api, angular2-routing

I get this error when try to work with rest api. 
Cannot find module `'./data.service` angular 2

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class GithubFollowersService extends DataService{

    constructor(http: Http) {
        super('https://api.github.com/users/mosh-hamedani/followers', http);
    }

}
```

Comment: Issue is with the `DataService` file location , `GithubFollowersService` and `DataService` are both on the same location?

Comment: the service folder path was incorrect that I was given. Now it is correct

Comment: check your data.service path

Comment: basically means data service is not in the same directory as GithubFollowersService or you aren't exporting it correctly (i.e., check: export class dataService)